# AppEngine flexible static index.html

Tags: google-app-engine, go, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to set up a AppEngine flexible (go) backend/api server together with a static frontend.

Ideally i would like to completely decouple the api server from the frontend so was planning to serve all the static files from cloud storage. I have managed to set this up by serving the static files on a subdomain from cloud storage - however, this means that users have to visit the subdomain to retrieve the index.html file.

Does anyone know if it is possible (in e.g. app.yml - but couldnt find anything in the docs here) to get fetch index.html from cloud storage?

I.e. such that:

https://example.com would return index.html from cloud storage
https://example.com/api is routed to my appengine service?

Comment: You can have the Go server proxy GCS, for instance: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#NewSingleHostReverseProxy

Comment: Thanks, thats of course a solution, but the I would not get the cdn advantage of cloud storage and all requests will have to be handled by the server - but if there is no other way i guess i can do that for index at least yes

Comment: Actually, thinking more about it, this is a good solution, proxying index and having all links in index refer to files at a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the "www" subdomain to be your index.html, then let your App Engine handle the [request routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-routed). Look into how [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) works and you will see how to do it.

Basically, let App Engine route all your default traffic to your index.html and then do the routine specific subdomains to whatever API handlers you have setup.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are saying - yes i could point the dns for www. to the static files, but that would not help me server @ for the webpage (all visitors would have to use www?)

ref dispatch.yaml - I tried to find out but it seems as if it can only forward routes to services, not to cloud storage directly?

Comment: You won't need GCS in that case, you can serve a static index.html directly from GAE.

If you really need GCS to serve your index.html for some reason, you can set it to serve on "www" and then reroute your naked domain to it via [code](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/google-app-engine-redirection-naked-domain-www/).

Comment: Thanks, i realize that i can serve it from gae, the point of the question was if it could be avoided, wanting to have the to parts fully de-coupled.

Comment: Yeah, you can but with code. Just setup a redirect code on the naked domain to redirect to your "www" (which is your GCS), then it should work.